# How to draw path with width just like canvas 2d lineTo

Tags: webgl, three.js

How to draw path with width just like canvas 2d lineTo. I think THREE.Line is very approximate to my requirement, but I found that line's width couldn't be bigger than 1 in some platform. Any alternative to achieve this purpose?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

the linewidth (and caps etc) are set as attributes of the *material,* not the line. So just assign (as a test) material.linewidth = 3 and try it out. Look at the build/three.js code listing of THREE.LineBasicMaterial for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that we can set line width by LineBasicMaterial, but in my windows xp,  ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE= 1 - 1, so any value beyonds this range is invalid, this is what annoys me.

Comment: if canvas can draw it, three.js will draw it -- it just calls the canvas ops.

Comment: so are you saying you want three.js to provide line drawing capabilities that canvas does *not* have?

Comment: Oh, I mean that line width can't be set to larger than 1 in webgl. I have fixed this issue by calculating the points to simulate a line and drawn it with THREE.Ribbon. My current problem is that ribbon can't make the end round, I need draw a circle to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the line width limit I think you'd have to generate the line geometry yourself as triangles rather than relying on GL to draw thick lines. The canvas2d line does some weird stuff though (http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/hWmWT/)

Another alternative is to add some 2d offset to your line drawing code and draw the same lines multiple times changing the offset each time.

http://github.com/corbanbrook/webgl-2d might have what you need

Comment: Yes, you're right. If there's a library encapsulates this functionality, it'll be great. I notice that three.js has a class "THREE.Ribbon", I'm not sure if this can meet my demand. I have checked http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/hWmWT/, I think that these points are too close, (256, 256) (256, 257).

Comment: Check out https://github.com/corbanbrook/webgl-2d
I don't understand your comment about "points are too close". There's no such thing as "too close". There's just the spec and what it says happens. Clearly the spec says something different than I think most people would expect. It'd expect it to draw 2 or 3 large rectangles 100x100 pixels large, each 1 pixel offset from the previous. Instead what it looks like lineWidth does is generate geometry lineWidth / 2 units perpendicular to the direction of the line on each side of the line, connects the ends and then fills the result.

Comment: What I want say is that the distance of three points is 1, and the lineWidth is 10, I think it'll not work very well, if the distance is 10, and the lineWidth is 2, it must work.Thanks.